# How to show that $X_n/n$ approaches a constant as $n \to \infty$ if $X_n \tilde\ \chi_{n-p}^2$

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, random-variable, convergence

Page 18 [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/18/lecture-18.pdf) states that  if $X_n \sim \chi_{n-p}^2$ with fixed $p$, then $X_n/n$ approaches a constant. How do I show this?

Comment: Envision $X_n$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-p} Y_i^2$ where the $Y_i$'s are iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X_n \sim \text{ChiSq}(n-p)$ then you can consult the moments of the [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) to see that you have mean and variance:

$$\mathbb{E} \Big( \frac{X_n}{n} \Big) = 1
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\mathbb{V} \Big( \frac{X_n}{n} \Big) = \frac{2}{n}.$$

Thus, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the variance shrinks to zero.  Now, if you apply [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) you should be able to show that this implies converges in probability to a constant.